# Applescripts getElementByName().value not working

Tags: applescript

I tried to fill a web form with the data from Excel using AppleScript, but Safari said:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByName('txtnama')[0].value=txtnama')
```

Here's the code :

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate

    set txtnama to value of cell "I2"

    tell application "Safari"
        activate

        do JavaScript "

        var txtnama= '" & txtnama & "'; 

        document.getElementsByName("txtnama")[0].value=txtnama;" in document 1

    end tell
end tell
```

The element of the form I'm trying to fill is:

```
<input type="text" name="txtnama" style="width:300px;" maxlength="80" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are mismatched and/or unescaped, but the basic code is correct.  Here is the *Safari* part of your code re-formatted with correct quoting:

```
    tell application "Safari"

        do JavaScript ¬
            "var txtnama=" & quoted form of txtnama & ";" & ¬
            "document.getElementsByName('txtnama')[0].value=" & ¬
            quoted form of txtnama ¬
            in document 1

    end tell
```

You also shouldn't nest the *Safari* `tell` block inside the *Microsoft Excel* `tell` block unless there's specific reason to do so.  Therefore, move the `end tell` at the end to just after you define your variable `txtnama`.  It should be laid out like this:

```
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        -- Commands sent to Excel
    end tell


    tell application "Safari"
        -- Commands sent to Safari (As above)
    end tell
```